# The signed integer overflow in C

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why when I compile this, C tells me that sum cannot be represented as `int`?
I have no idea how to debug this one. I thought the struct I created is all good and also the count sum function. So please help me to figure out what's wrong inside the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *my_list();
int sum_list_values(struct node *list);


int main(){
    struct node *list = my_list();
    int sum = sum_list_values(list);
    printf("%d", sum);

    return 0;
}


struct node *my_list(){
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = 1;

    struct node *new1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = 3;

    struct node *new2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = 3;

    struct node *new3 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = 7;

    new->next = new1;
    new1->next = new2;
    new2->next = new3;
    new3->next = NULL;


    return new;
}

int sum_list_values(struct node *list){
    struct node *current = list;
    int sum = 0;

    while(current != NULL){
        printf("Hello");
        sum = sum + current->data;//counter
        current = current->next;//increment
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: sum_list_values should check, If next != NULL before incrementing.

Comment: Please quote the error/warning verbatim and completly.

Comment: avoid `new` as variable names. It's a C++ keyword.

Comment: if you had 50 notes to create, would you paste your `malloc` line 50 times?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why, perfectly OK as a C one! At least this proves that OP is not using a C++ compiler.

Comment: Your program reads from uninitialized memory: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/cad8b06c

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the issue is when those keywords end up in the `.h` file and you want to include them in your C++ project. I stumbled upon a file with `class` and `this` in the `.h` file...

Answer (score 2):

You have made a small unnoticeable mistake

Code Section which is

```
struct node *new1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new->data = 3;

struct node *new2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new->data = 3;

struct node *new3 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new->data = 7;
```

Value is assigned to the same node each time , newly created node is left with unassigned data (poor nodes).

It Should be instead

```
struct node *new1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new1->data = 3;

struct node *new2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new2->data = 3;

struct node *new3 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new3->data = 7;
```

Hope this will help.

Keep asking , keep growing :)

Comment: Well found, that fixes the read of uninitialized memory that was the only problem in the question's snippet: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/d13f915c